# Agregar producto

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Tengo un html que lo uso de formulario en el cual el usuario ingresa un producto (nombre, descripción, url de la imagen, precio) y quisiera que al completarlo, los datos se guarden en otro html donde hay una lista de productos. Realicé código js pero todavía no encuentro la manera en que el producto ingresado se muestre en pantalla. La idea es que al completar los datos del formulario y presionar agregar el sitio te redireccione al otro html con la lista de productos y el producto agregado por el usuario. Comparto a continuación el código:

***Lista de Productos:***

```html
  <section class="products" id="product-list">

    <button class="add-product"><a href="agregar-producto.html">Agregar Producto</a></button>

    <div class="shop-content">             
        <div class="import">

            <h2>Productos importados</h2>

            <div class="product-box" data-name="p-4">

                <div>
                     <img src="imagenes/taladro.png" alt="Taladro" class="product-img">
                     <h2 class="product-title">Taladro 13mm</h2>
                 </div>
                <span class="price">$15.000</span>
                <button class="show-product" data-id="1" >Ver producto</button>
            </div>
    
            <div class="product-box" data-name="p-8">
    
                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/Grasera Manual.png" alt="Grasera" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Grasera Manual</h2>
                </div>  
                <span class="price">$13.000</span>
                <button class="show-product" data-id="4" >Ver producto</button>
            </div>
    
            <div class="product-box" data-name="p-12">
    
                <div>
                    <img src="imagenes/hidrolavadora.png" alt="hidrolavadora" class="product-img">
                    <h2 class="product-title">Hidrolavadora</h2>
                </div>
                <span class="price">$15.000</span>
                <button class="show-product" data-id="12" >Ver producto</button>
            </div>
        
        </div>
   
    </div>

</section>

<div id="product-list-form"></div>
```

***Formulario***

```html
<body>

    <div class="login-box">
    <img class="avatar" src="imagenes/punto i logo.png" alt="Logo Punto i S.R.L.">
    <h1>Agregue su producto</h1>
    <form id="product-form">

        <label for="Usuario">Url Imagen</label>
        <input class="login-input url-form" id="username" type="url" placeholder="https://www.image.png">

        <label for="Contraseña">Producto</label>
        <input class="login-input name-form" id="password" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre del Producto">

        <label for="Contraseña">Descripción</label>
        <input class="login-input description-form" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Descripción">

        <label for="Contraseña">Precio</label>
        <input class="login-input price-form" id="username" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Ingrese Precio">

        <button type="submit" class="button-input"><a href="carterleria.html">Agregar</a></button>

    </form>

</div>

<script src="archivos js\add-product.js"></script>

</body>
```

***Código JS***

```js
document.getElementById('product-form').addEventListener('submit', function (){

    const url = document.querySelector('.url-form').value;

    const name = document.querySelector('.name-form').value;

    const description = document.querySelector('.description-form').value;

    const price = document.querySelector('.price-form').value;

    const product = new Product(url,name,description,price);

    const ui = new UI();

    ui.addProduct(product);

});

class Product{

    constructor(url,name,description,price){

        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;

    }

}

class UI{

    addProduct(product){

        const productList = document.getElementById('product-list-form');

        const element = document.createElement('div');

        element.innerHTML = `
        
    <div class="product-box" data-name="p-1">

        <div>
             <img src="${product.url}" class="product-img">
             <h2 class="product-title">${product.name}</h2>
             <p>${product.description}</p>
        </div>
        <span class="price">${product.price}/span>
        <button class="show-product" data-id="8" >Ver producto</button>
   
    </div>`;

    productList.appendChild(element);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haría sería guardar un array en localStorage de los elementos y al guardar el elemento del formulario ocurra lo siguiente:

1. Insertar un elemento en el array del localStorage.
2. Indicarle al html de la lista que actualice en base al array del localStorage.

Con eso evitarías estar concatenando html y podrías faciltarte el actualizar elementos de la lista.

Comment: Entiendo la idea. Más o menos sería crear un array vacío y vincularlo a un localStorage y con un escuchador de eventos al presionar agregar hacer un push, Si mal no entendí sería algo así? Yo no tengo mucha experiencia con localStorage y no sabría como escribirlo en código.

Comment: Correcto. Puedes revisar este comentario para tener una idea de como funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762443/1617491